# Update gitlab file with data contained in .txt file using the API

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, gitlab-api

I am trying to update a gitlab file of mine with data contained in a file on my local machine e.g. /tmp/output.txt using the gitlab API without success so far.
So far I am able to update a file by just adding some text:

```
curl --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: MY_TOKEN \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"branch": "master",
    "author_email": "someone@email.com", "author_name": "someone", "content": "some content", "commit_message": "update file"}' \
    "https://gitlab.server.lan/api/v4/projects/xxxx/repository/files/my_file%2Fmy_yaml_file.yml"
```

But not by adding the contents of a txt file of my preference.

I would be grateful for some help!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can update a file with this snippet, but you want to replace/overwrite a file instead of append the content?

Comment: What is the response you get from that request? It looks like you're missing at least one quote on your first line, so what you have produces a syntax error for me. Other than that, this works as written assuming your token is valid... Can you provide the _exact_ command you are using and the output from the job?